# echoing some text in a text area through PHP

Tags: php

I want to echo some text inside the text area, just as we echo simple text(varchar) in the php script.
Can you help me

Comment: Do you want the page to load with text in the textarea, or you want to follow a longer process thru messages going to the textare while your php script is still running? (Doing some batch processing).

Comment: Please, provide us more information so we can help you better.

Answer (score 3):

echoing something in text area is different from echoing something in text field.

It should be something like this

```
<textarea><?php echo $somtext;?> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

(always escape entities, or even better use some anti-xss function)

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlentities($sometext);?> </textarea>
```